# Running a ruby shell with space in name from powershell

Tags: ruby, powershell

I am unable to run ruby files that has space in their name in powershell.
For example I can run

> ruby testfile.rb

but **not**

> ruby true or false.rb (the file name is true or false)

It will result in the error

> C:\Ruby200\bin\ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- true (LoadError)

Comment: `ruby "true or false.rb"`?

Comment: Thanks this helps